# Expected number of steps to walk through points by multiple walkers

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there are $m$ points.
A walker can visit the points in any order, but it will not visit a point twice.
There are $n$ walkers, and their starting points are randomly chosen.

After $k$ steps, each point is visited at least once by any of the walkers.
What is the expected number of $k$?

Some assumptions:

- a walker doesn't know the visited points of other walkers
- multiple walkers can be at the same position

Additional question:

What if walkers are capable of knowing the visited points of others after they have chosen their random starting points? (so the first assumption doesn't hold anymore)

Comment: Can two walkers be at the same element at the same step ?

Comment: @Furrane Yes, they can. In addition, a walker has no idea about where the other walkers are.

Comment: do they always stay walking in the same direction ?  if so via pigeonhole principle $\lfloor{m\over n}\rfloor+1$ is the minimum number needed. but as to the expected value on average with random stuff you're better off asking somebody who's not me.

Comment: I'm concerned with your last edit, doesn't that in theory allow someone to jump m-1 and effectively walk backwards ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks for pointing out. I removed the redundant assumptions and restated my question.

Comment: are the paths straight ? sorry keep thinking like this might be a planar geometry or graph theory question as well ( not that I know much about either).

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The paths don't have to be straight. A walker can go to any unvisited point. If B is accidentally on the path from A to C, we don't think B is visited since it is not the destination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61828/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-chengxin-ma).

Comment: This most confused and most ambiguous question seems to be concerned with **independent self-avoiding random walks on the complete graph**. That is, for every $i\leqslant n$ and $t\leqslant m$, the position $X^i_t$ of walker $i$ at time $t$ would be uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\setminus\{X^i_1,\ldots,X^i_{t-1}\}$. And the $n$ processes $(X^i)_i$ would be independent. Is this correct? (I am not commenting on the Additional question, which lacks some other key information.)

Comment: @Did yes you are right. The additional question is just assuming the walkers are not independent anymore, given the ability to know others' visited points. But still, each walker is self-avoiding.

Comment: Then the mentions of "the plane" are all highly misleading.

Comment: Einar got the correct answer, I can't speak for the demonstration in itself, but he obtains numbers that match the simulation like a glove.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start to reformulate the question slightly, which will also make it clear if I have misunderstood the question.

Basically, there are $m$ points and $n$ walkers. Walkers pick points at random, one at a time without replacement, so that after round $k$ each walker has picked $k$ points at random.

If we just look at round $k$ without thinking about the sequential nature of picking points, each walker has picked $k$ points at random, independent of the other walkers.

The question we now ask is: *What is the likelihood $q_k$ that when $n$ walkers each pick $k$ out of $m$ points, all points will be picked by at least one walker?*

If we can answer that question for any $k$, the likelihood that the last points were picked in round $k$ will be $p_k = q_k-q_{k-1}$.

Now, let's keep the number of points, $m$, and round, $k$, fixed and instead vary the number of walkers, $n$.

Let the random variable $X_n$ be the number of unpicked points when there are $n$ walkers: ie, the likelihood of $X_n=x$ for some $x$ is the likelihood that with $n$ walkers, there will remain exactly $x$ points not picked by any of the walkers.

If there is only one walker, obviously $X_1=m-k$ (ie the likelihood of $X_1=m-k$ is one) since that one walker has picked $k$ points and $m-k$ thus remain unpicked.

If there are two walkers, each have picked $k$ points at random out of the $m$ points, so the number of unpicked points follows a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution): $X_2\sim\text{Hypergeom}(m-k,m-k,m)$.

If there are $n$ walkers, and the first $n-1$ walkers have left $X_{n-1}$ points unpicked, the number of points also not picked by the $n$th walker will be
$$
X_n \sim \text{Hypergeom}(X_{n-1},m-k,m)
$$
which basically gives us a recursive expression for $X_n$.

I came across this type of iterated hypergeometric distrubutions when studying [sequence shuffling](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0001867800000835), where I found these could be expressed in terms of [generalised hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). To make a long story short,
$$
\text{E}\left[ (1+u)^{X_n}\right]
=\sum_{i=0}^{m-k} 
  \frac{[(m-k)(m-k-1)\cdots(m-k-i+1)]^n}{[m(m-1)\cdots(m-i+1)]^{n-1}} 
  \frac{u^i}{i!}
=\sum_{i=0}^{m-k} 
  \frac{\left(\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-k-i)!}\right)^n}
    {\left(\frac{m!}{(m-i)!}\right)^{n-1}} \frac{u^i}{i!}.
$$
I'll show how to derive this further down.

In terms of hypergeometric functions, this is
$$
\text{E}\left[ (1+u)^{X_n}\right]
= {}_{n}F_{n-1}(k-m,\ldots,k-m;-m,\ldots,-m;-u)
$$
where ${}_{n}F_{n-1}$ takes $n$ times the parameter $-(m-k)$ in the numerator and $n-1$ times the parameter $-m$ in the denominator.

This gives the probability generating function
$$
\text{E}\left[t^{X_n}\right]
= \sum_{x=0}^m \Pr[X_n=x]\cdot t^x
=\sum_{i=0}^{m-k} 
  \frac{\left(\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-k-i)!}\right)^n}
    {\left(\frac{m!}{(m-i)!}\right)^{n-1}} \frac{(t-1)^i}{i!}
= {}_{n}F_{n-1}(k-m,\ldots,k-m;-m,\ldots,-m;1-t).
$$

The likelihood that all points have been picked, ie $\Pr[X_n=0]$, is then found by entering $t=0$:
$$
\Pr[X_n=0]
=\sum_{i=0}^{m-k} 
  \frac{\left(\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-k-i)!}\right)^n}
    {\left(\frac{m!}{(m-i)!}\right)^{n-1}} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
= {}_{n}F_{n-1}(k-m,\ldots,k-m;-m,\ldots,-m;1).
$$

Thus, given the $n$ walkers and instead varying the number of rounds, the likelihood that all points have been picked in round $k$ or earlier is
$$
q_k = {}_{n}F_{n-1}(k-m,\ldots,k-m;-m,\ldots,-m;1)
$$
which makes
$$
p_k
= q_k-q_{k-1}
= {}_{n}F_{n-1}(k-m,\ldots,k-m;-m,\ldots,-m;1)
 - {}_{n}F_{n-1}(k-1-m,\ldots,k-1-m;-m,\ldots,-m;1).
$$

I recall there is quite a bit of theory about how to compute these, recursions as well as numerical methods, but don't remember all that very well. You should be able to use math packages like Maple or Mathematica to do them. Eg, typing `hypergeom([-3,-3,-3],[-5,-5],1)` into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) gives you $q_2=9/50$ for $m=5$, $n=3$.

---

**Derivation of the hypergeometric series:**

Given $m$ points and $n$ walkers, each picking $k$ points at random, let $X_k$ be the number of points not picked by any walker.

For any selection of $r$ points, the likelihood that a walker has not picked any of these points is $\binom{m-r}{k}/\binom{m}{k}$: ie the number of ways to pick $k$ points from the remaining $m-r$ divided by the number of ways to pick them from from all $m$ points. Thus, the likelihood that none of the $n$ walker pick any of these $r$ points is $[\binom{m-r}{k}/\binom{m}{k}]^n$.

Since there are $\binom{m}{r}$ different ways to pick the $r$ points, the expected number of ways to pick $r$ points which none of the walkers have selected is $\binom{m}{r}\cdot[\binom{m-r}{k}/\binom{m}{k}]^n$.

However, the number of ways to pick $r$ points not picked by any of the walkers can also be expressed as $\text{E}[\binom{X_k}{r}]$. The equality between the two means that
$$
\text{E}\left[\binom{X_k}{r}\right]
= \binom{m}{r}\cdot\left(\frac{\binom{m-r}{k}}{\binom{m}{k}}\right)^n
= \frac{\left(\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-k-r)!}\right)^n}
    {\left(\frac{m!}{(m-r)!}\right)^{n-1}}
  \cdot\frac{1}{r!}.
$$
This gives us the desired result:
$$
\text{E}\left[(1+u)^{X_k}\right]
= \sum_{r=0}^m \text{E}\left[\binom{X_k}{r}\right] u^r
= \sum_{r=0}^m
   \frac{\left(\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-k-r)!}\right)^n}
    {\left(\frac{m!}{(m-r)!}\right)^{n-1}}
  \cdot\frac{u^r}{r!}.
$$

---

**Computed example with $m=6$ points and $n=5$ walkers:**

This makes:
$$
q_1 = \text{hypergeom}([-5,-5,-5,-5,-5],[-6,-6,-6,-6],1) = 0 \\
q_2 = \text{hypergeom}([-4,-4,-4,-4,-4],[-6,-6,-6,-6],1) = 6026/16875 \\
q_3 = \text{hypergeom}([-3,-3,-3,-3,-3],[-6,-6,-6,-6],1) = 130767/160000 \\
q_4 = \text{hypergeom}([-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],[-6,-6,-6,-6],1) = 49376/50625 \\
q_5 = \text{hypergeom}([-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],[-6,-6,-6,-6],1) = 1295/1296 \\
q_6 = \text{hypergeom}([-0,-0,-0,-0,-0],[-6,-6,-6,-6],1) = 1
$$
which gives probabilities
$p_1=0$,
$p_2=6026/16875\approx 0.357$,
$p_3=1988053/4320000\approx 0.460$,
$p_4=2048129/12960000\approx 0.158$,
$p_5=239/10000=0.0239$,
$p_6=1/1296\approx 0.00077$ for the likelihood $p_k$ of having picked all points after round $k$.

Comment: As I posted under the post's chat, I coded a little bit of a simulation for this, and I will soon try and see if your reasonning hold against the simulation (it looks nice to me but to be honest it's a little bit out of my league).

I'll have a look at hypergeometric formula and come back later with sim Vs theory, great work indeed !

Comment: @Furrane: If you give me some numbers, I can do the computations using hypergeometric functions and post them here.

Comment: Indeed I'm confused about hypergeometric formula, check the extended comment section of the author's post for the numbers.

Comment: @Furrane: I added a computed example using $m=6$, $n=5$, so if you run a simulation enough times to get a good statistic of how many times all points are picked after $k$ rounds, you can compare with my computed probabilities $p_k$.

Comment: Congratulation, it looks like your computation is correct !
Number of cases : 100000

k=1, frequence=0.0
k=2, frequence=0.35794
k=3, frequence=0.46061
k=4, frequence=0.1573
k=5, frequence=0.02343
k=6, frequence=0.00072

Comment: Here is the code I used for reference (yes I know, it's ugly haha)  https://pastebin.com/wgShiX9E

Answer (score 0):

Einar's answer is definitely the one you should tag as an answer but I'll try and answer for your additional question.

If Walkers are capable of knowing which points have already been visited, and assuming their movement restriction expand to that knowledge (ie : they can't move to an already visited point, no matter the walker that visited it), then it is important to understand that it is the first step that fully determine $k$ (the step at which each points is visited).

First step is unique in that, it's the only step for wich walkers are allowed to be on the same point. But after that first step, each new step will see $n$ points visited, until all are.

So let's detail what happens in the first step :

- The first walker $n_1$ picks a point at random. His probability to pick an unvisited point is $P_1=1$ since there are only unvisited points at this stage.
- The second walker $n_2$ well he's facing a pool of $m-1$ unvisited points and $1$ visited point so his probability to pick an unvisited point is $P_2 = {m-1\over m}$.
- What's tricky for the third (and the following) walkers is that you have to account for how $n_2$ did before : either $n_2$ reached an unvisited point then $P_3 = {m-2\over m}$ or he did not and $P_3 = {m-1\over m}$ (pardon my weak notations here)

This is close to the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

From there we can reason with expectation :
Let $E_i(m)$ be the expected number of steps requiered for an unvisited point to be visited with $m$ total points and $i-1$ visited points, then $$E_i(m) = {m\over m+1-i}$$

So then, with $n$ walkers, the expected number of visited points at step $1$ is $v_1$ with :

$$v_1 = \max_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\left( j \;|\; \sum_{i=1}^j E_i(m)\le n \right)$$

*To clarify the notation this is $v_1$ is the highest integer $j$ so that the sum is less than $n$*

Once you got this, you can easily deduce $k$ since, as discussed at the start, once you know $v1$ there is no randomness as far as reaching every points visited, you just add $n$ each step until you're over $m$. With a more mathematical notation :

$$ k= \min_{j\in\mathbb{N}^*}\left( j-1\;|\; v_1 + (j-1)\cdot n \ge m \right)$$

I did my best to explain it but I'm not a pro at this, feel free to ask or correct me if I'm wrong.